# From a running PHP Code, how to update status in DIV tag

Tags: javascript, php

I have a web Page, in which i an downloading data one after another in a loop. After each data download is finished i want to update the status to a DIV tag in the Web Page. How can i do this. Connecting to server and downloading data via php  code and the div tag is within the .phtml page.

i have tried

```
echo "
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            $('#tstData').show();
            </script>
            ";
```

But the echo statement update will happen at the end only. Refreshing of DIV tag need to happen at the end of each download.

Comment: And where is your download code ?

Comment: use AJAX so on success it will update the page

Comment: maybe you do not fully understand the server/client principle. php is executed on the server side. once you're on the client side, php can't do anything anymore.

Comment: have you got your answer ?

Comment: @VeenaSujith Will please let know is your problem solved or not with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery load()

```
$('#testData').load('http://URL to script that is downloading and formatting data to display');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#save_card").submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var url = "card_save.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           dataType:"json",
           data: $("#save_card").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.msg=="success")
                {
                  $("#submit_msg").html("Thank You !!!");
                  console.log("Record has been Inserted Successfully!!!");
                }

               else
               {
                   $("#submit_msg").html(data.er);
                   console.log("There Is Some Error");
               }
                $("#submit_msg").show();
                setTimeout(function() { $("#submit_msg").hide(); }, 5000);
                $("#save_card").get(0).reset();

           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.class_master

});
```

Use This Ajax function to call PHP function to get data. Here

1. `#save_card` = Id of the form that you want to submit.
2. url = action for the form or the location to the php file from where your data is coming.
3. `data: $("#save_card").serialize()` = it is sending all the data of the form in serialize form. Data can be created manually to do this repalce this line with `data: {'name':name,'year':year}`
4. `function(data)` = here data is returned from the php code in json formate.
5. `data.msg` = It is a way to access different field from data.

   ```
       $user_email = $_REQUEST['user_email'];
       $cat_id = $_REQUEST['category'];
       $title = $_REQUEST['title'];
       $country = $_REQUEST['country'];
       $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
       $sql = "INSERT INTO project(title, user_email, cat_id, country, start_date) VALUES ('$title','$user_email','$cat_id','$country', '$date')";

       if (mysql_query($sql)) {
           $project_id = mysql_insert_id();
           echo json_encode(array('project_id' => $project_id, 'msg' => 'Successfully Added', 'status' => 'true'));
       } else {
           echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Not Added', 'status' => 'false'));
       }
   ```

PHP code to send data in json format